# Update relationship record in saverecord event of force:recorddata

Tags: lds

I am trying the default the account Id when creating the contact. But I am unable to save the contact record. I am getting account id from console.log.

Please suggest me what am I doing wrong here.

```
handleSaveContact: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.newContact.AccountId", component.get('v.ConAccountId'));
    var recordaction=component.get('v.ContactId')==null?'contactRecordCreator':'ldsContactEdit';
    component.find(recordaction).saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            console.log(saveResult.state);
            // record is saved successfully
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // handle the incomplete state
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
            // handle the error state
            console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Lakshmi

Answer (score 0):

component.find(recordaction) take the aura-id which you have assigned to the force:recorddata in cmp.
for example

```
<force:recordData aura:id="record"
    layoutType="FULL"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}"
    targetRecord="{!v.record}"
    targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    mode="VIEW"/>

so,
in this case it will be component.find(record)...
```

Comment: The aura-id is dynamic based on below expression.  My problem is I am not able default account when creating new contact.      var recordaction=component.get('v.ContactId')==null?'contactRecordCreator':'ldsContactEdit';

Comment: you cant create aura-id dynamically you have to give some static value